# why does body.scrollHeight automatically increase but not decrease

Tags: iframe, scroll, scrollbar, document-body

My iframe.body has a `scrollHeight` property which I believe is read only
I don't understand how it gets set.

When I modify the `iframe.body.innerHTML` with some ***larger*** HTML, I notice the `iframe.body.scrollHeight` **increases**. Great! When we set `$('#previewWindow').height(iframeDocument.body.scrollHeight)` this means that the scrollbar is the right height for the new larger content

However....

When I modify the `iframe.body.innerHTML` with some ***smaller*** HTML, I notice the `iframe.body.scrollHeight` **remains the same**. NOT great! When we set `$('#previewWindow').height(iframeDocument.body.scrollHeight)` and this means that the scrollbar is too long and there's loads of whitespace to scroll to at the bottom of the inner content of the iframe

Why does it increase but not decrease in the same logical way?
What would be the best workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I made a workaround, I first set the height to 0 each time, then whatever I put into the innerHTML must be bigger! This all seems a bit strange though. $('#iframe').height(0)